# How to select the rows based on number of columns in a cell matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell

I have a cell matrix of size 248*15 with the maximum number of columns 15. I want to extract the rows containing greater than or equal to 8(>=8) non-zero column entries in MatLab.

For example: cell row 1,2,7,8,.....

[Find attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bgzq.png)

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a valid question. However, adding sample code or what you have tried so far is indicative and shows effort. Check my solution below and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cellfun` to first determine which cell elements are empty, and then use array indexing to select the rows as required:

```
C = {} % The cell matrix of size 248 x 15.

% An array of 248 x 15 that has Booleans based on empty or not:
emptyCells = cellfun(@isempty, C)

% The total number of empty columns on each row:
emptyColsCount = sum(emptyCells, 2)

% Find those rows with at least 8 non-zero columns
requiredRowIndices = find(emptyColsCount < 8)
% This returns [1, 2, 7, ...]
```